# defining rule for derivative on arbitrary function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, rule

Is there a way in Mathematica for defining rules for derivatives on undefined functions? For example, I would like to define a rule such that for any function $f(x,y)$, when I take the $x$-derivative it gives me a function $\delta f$:

```
D[f[x,y],x] -> δf[x,y]
D[g[x,y],x] -> δg[x,y]
```

etc.

EDIT: I should clarify that I am looking for a rule that could act on functions of any type, so not just $f$, $g$, but any function of $(x,y)$.

Comment: Do you really want to create a new symbol with a $\delta$ in front, or do you just want to display $f^{(1,0)}$ as $\delta f$?

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative):

```
f /: Derivative[1,0][f] = f;
f /: Derivative[0,1][f] = g;
```

Then:

```
D[f[x, y], x]
D[f[x, y], y]
```

> f[x, y]
>
> g[x, y]

Comment: I should clarify that I am looking for a rule that could act on functions of any type, so not just f,g, but any function of [x,y]. So the rule would append $\delta$ to any function where I take $\partial_x$.